# maven packaging jar with jndi datasource

Tags: java, maven, jetty, jndi

If I package the application as a war, I can set the jndi datasource using web.xml and jetty-env.xml. But I want to package my application as jar and my understanding is that u cant use web.xml and jetty-env.xml in that case. I have set the datasource to be jndi looked up. how can I solve this.Is there any special way where I can point to the jetty-env.xml from my maven pom file?

Following is my jetty-spring xml

```
<beans>

  <bean id="contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>

  <bean id="triggerServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">

    <property name="threadPool">  
      <bean id="ThreadPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <property name="minThreads" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxThreads" value="50"/>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="connectors">
      <list>
        <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
          <property name="port" value="2080"/>
        </bean>
      </list>
    </property>

    <property name="handler">
      <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <property name="handlers">
          <list>
            <ref bean="contexts"/>
            <ref bean="testHandler"/>           
          </list>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="stopAtShutdown" value="true"/>
    <property name="sendServerVersion" value="true"/>
    <property name="sendDateHeader" value="true"/>
    <property name="gracefulShutdown" value="1000"/>
  </bean>
```

Following is the java code which start the server.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        TriggerServer.init();
        Server server = (Server)springContext.getBean("triggerServer"); 
        logInfo(server);

        server.start();             
        server.join();         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("?", e);
    }
}
```

and following is my jetty-env.xml

```
<Configure id="thisfile" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/jndiDB</Arg>
    <Arg>
     <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>
    <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</Set>
    <Set name="User">user</Set>
    <Set name="Password">password</Set>
    <Set name="connectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
    <Set name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <New class="java.util.Properties">
            <Call name="setProperty">
                <Arg>MinLimit</Arg>
                <Arg>5</Arg>
            </Call>
            <!-- put the other properties in here too -->
        </New>
    </Set>

</New>
    </Arg>
</New>
</Configure>
```

Edited and including pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.client.project</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.client.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>application</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        .....
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ......
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>application</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                            <excludeScope>test</excludeScope>
                            <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>jetty-jsp-2.1,jetty-all-server</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/dist
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Specification-Version>3.1</Specification-Version>
                            <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why not packaging as a war file?

Comment: Client wants to start it as a server, like this::::
Server server = (Server)springContext.getBean("triggerServer");
   
   server.start();
   server.join();

Comment: Simplest solution is to use a war and afterwards rename it simply. Can you post your pom file?

Comment: I added the pom file in the edited question.Thanks for the interest in trying to help me out :)

Comment: I think there should be a way to point to the jetty-env.xml from the pom file.If its a war we are building, then its taken to consideration automatically.But here, in this case of jar, application load the spring context.triggerServer is also a spring bean.

Comment: Where have you put the jetty-env.xml file? Furthermore in my opinion packaging a webapp into jar does not make sense in particular with Maven.

Comment: this is because we need to function the project in 2 ways.1 is as webapp where we have no problem building the project as war. Other way is to build the project as jar to start server as embedded jetty.jetty-spring file is the configuration for this?

Comment: afaik, jetty-env.xml is for use with maven jetty plugin.  However now you want to package the app to deploy to client, you shouldn't be relying on maven to launch your app anymore.  Should you have a look in how to properly embed jetty in you application instead?

Comment: jetty-env isn't just for the jetty-maven-plugin, it is generally useful when deploying a webapp into jetty for tweaking the WebAppContext as you would in a context.xml file

Comment: not sure if it helps you but there is some jetty-spring integration here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Spring